# mysql to mysqli class function conversion

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently I have following class, function structure for mysql in `functions.php`

`constants.php` contains database name, user password etc.

I want to use this class as **mysqli**.

**There are many class examples available online. But I couldn't make it....**

**If I can convert this to mysqli, I can save much time in changing class name etc on other all pages.**

I am giving sample code in my **`functions.php`** file. How can I convert it to mysqli ?

I have already tried [Mysqli Converter](https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool) But it didn't help me much...

```
<?
ob_start();
include_once("constants.php");
//create class 
Class bsq
{

function connect_db()
  {
    mysql_connect(HST,USR,PWD) or die(mysql_error()); //die("Failed to Connecting MYSQL");
    mysql_select_db(DBN) or die(mysql_error()); //die("Failed to connect database");
  }

function webdreamselect($table,$where,$start,$end,$orderby,$orderbyvalue)
  {

$sql="select * from ".$table."";
        if($where!="") {
        $sql.=" where ".$where."";
        }
        if($orderby!="" && $orderbyvalue!="" ) {
            $sql.=" order by ".$orderby." ".$orderbyvalue."";
        }
        if($end > 0 ) {

        $sql.=" limit ".$start.",".$end." ";
        }
        //echo $sql;
    $seldata=@mysql_query($sql);
    return $seldata;
 }

function webdreamupdate($tbl, $sf, $sv, $wf, $wv, $prn)
    {
    $query.=" UPDATE ".$tbl." SET " ;            

    /* Here updating fields and values are composed */

    if(is_array($sf))
    {
        if(sizeof($sf) > 0)
        {
            for($j=0; $j<sizeof($sf); $j++)
            {           
                $update_vars.= " $sf[$j] = '$sv[$j]' ";

                if($j<sizeof($sf)-1)
                $update_vars .= ", "; 
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $update_vars.= " $sf = '$sv' ";
    }

    $query.= $update_vars;

    /*Here condition is created*/

    if(is_array($wf))
    {
        if(sizeof($wf) > 0)
        {
            for($k=0; $k<sizeof($wf); $k++)
            {           
                $condition.= " $wf[$k] = '$wv[$k]' ";

                if($k<sizeof($wf)-1)
                $condition .= " and "; 
            }
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        if($wf)
            $condition = $wf." = '$wv' ";
        else
            $condition="1";
    }
    $query.= " WHERE $condition ";
    if($prn==1)
    {
        //echo $query;
    }
        //echo $query;
    $result = @mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: replace all mysql_ with mysqli_ in your functions.php file.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I convert it to mysqli ?

An answer straight to the point:

1. Open up the [manual page for mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and read it through.
2. Create a test script and practice for a while running various queries to make yourself familiar with mysqli.
3. Open your favorite code editor, load this file and set to rewrite.
4. Once it finished, try to test it.
5. In case you get some particular error during the process, you are welcome to google for it, and - if no luck - then ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Use your functions.php as like this (all mysql_ replaced with mysqli_)

```
<?
ob_start();
include_once("constants.php");
//create class 
Class bsq
{

function connect_db()
  {
    mysqli_connect(HST,USR,PWD) or die(mysqli_error()); //die("Failed to Connecting MYSQL");
    mysqli_select_db(DBN) or die(mysqli_error()); //die("Failed to connect database");
  }

function webdreamselect($table,$where,$start,$end,$orderby,$orderbyvalue)
  {

$sql="select * from ".$table."";
        if($where!="") {
        $sql.=" where ".$where."";
        }
        if($orderby!="" && $orderbyvalue!="" ) {
            $sql.=" order by ".$orderby." ".$orderbyvalue."";
        }
        if($end > 0 ) {

        $sql.=" limit ".$start.",".$end." ";
        }
        //echo $sql;
    $seldata=@mysqli_query($sql);
    return $seldata;
 }

function webdreamupdate($tbl, $sf, $sv, $wf, $wv, $prn)
    {
    $query.=" UPDATE ".$tbl." SET " ;            

    /* Here updating fields and values are composed */

    if(is_array($sf))
    {
        if(sizeof($sf) > 0)
        {
            for($j=0; $j<sizeof($sf); $j++)
            {           
                $update_vars.= " $sf[$j] = '$sv[$j]' ";

                if($j<sizeof($sf)-1)
                $update_vars .= ", "; 
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $update_vars.= " $sf = '$sv' ";
    }

    $query.= $update_vars;

    /*Here condition is created*/

    if(is_array($wf))
    {
        if(sizeof($wf) > 0)
        {
            for($k=0; $k<sizeof($wf); $k++)
            {           
                $condition.= " $wf[$k] = '$wv[$k]' ";

                if($k<sizeof($wf)-1)
                $condition .= " and "; 
            }
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        if($wf)
            $condition = $wf." = '$wv' ";
        else
            $condition="1";
    }
    $query.= " WHERE $condition ";
    if($prn==1)
    {
        //echo $query;
    }
        //echo $query;
    $result = @mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: will changing mysql to mysqli in functions.php do ?

Comment: check it so you come to know what is happening.

Comment: What made you to write such an answer? do you have any experience with mysqli?

Comment: ok @YourCommonSense can you suggest what should be way to deal with it. So i can also learn

Comment: Can you answer my question please? What made you write this answer? What is the reason?

Comment: I have experience with traditional function based mysql_ and mysql_ instead object based mysqli.

Comment: Well, please refrain from answering questions in the area you have no experience with. thank you in advance.